# What consequence does XCode 4.5 not supporting armv6 devices have?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been reading about how XCode 4.5 has dropped support for armv6 but have not found a definitive statement about what the consequence of this are in terms of what devices/OSs can be supported when building with XCode 4.5.

I'm targeting my app at 4.n, 5.n and 6.n devices, however on 4.n I'm getting a runtime crash with

`dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValu`e

Might this be related to XCode 4.5 no longer supporting armv6?

Comment: When you say "4.n", what is 'n' exactly?

Comment: I've tried with a 4.0.1 and 4.3.1 device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 and no support for armv6 means that you can only support iOS 4.3 and later. It means your app won't run on the original iPhone or the iPhone 3G. It won't run on the 1st or 2nd gen iPod touch.

Comment: So if somebody is releasing an app in the app store and they want to support devices as far back as 4.0 how do they do that? Do they have to release two versions of the app? If you use 4.5 you can't make an app for < 4.3, but if you use an old XCode presumably the build won't run on 6.n? So you have to release two versions of the app?

Comment: There is no point in supporting ancient devices. Hardly anyone uses these any more. Our app was showing less than 5% 4.3 and that was before the iPhone 5 shipped. 95% of our traffic was on 5.0 or higher.

Comment: But what is the answer regardless of that?

Comment: At the moment, Apple still appears to be accepting app submissions for apps built with versions of Xcode prior to 4.5 (4.4, perhaps 4.3). With these older versions of Xcode you can create an app that supports iOS 4.0. However, such an app would not be able to use any iOS 6 features (but it should run under iOS 6) and such an app would not be able to support the 4" screen of the iPhone 5 or 5th gen iPod touch. So yes, for now, you could submit two apps. One that supports older devices, built with Xcode 4.4, and a second that supports newer devices and iOS 6, built with Xcode 4.5.